# How do I transform my Scala XML object (of class Elem) to HTML using XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, scala, xslt

I have a small piece of code that, given the paths of my XML and XSLT files, outputs an HTML file in the provided path. It goes like this:

```
  try {
       val tFactory: TransformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance
       val transformer: Transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("<PATH TO XSL>"))
       transformer.transform(new StreamSource("<PATH TO XML>"), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("PATH TO HTML")))
 } catch {
       case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
 }
```

Now, instead of an XML file as an input, I want to input a Scala `Elem` object. How do I make that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create string from your element.

```
val xml = <elem/>
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml.toString())), new StreamResult(writer))
```

Comment: I did exactly hits before you answered. Thanks anyway!